# Content duplicity in cq5 page

Tags: components, aem

I am observing content duplicity on my CQ5 page, i cross-checked for any duplicacy of property names in the component's dialog, however, there were none. However, the duplicacy for the properties have occured only with the xtpye as "richtext". Can there be any other reason for this?

Comment: imprecise and vague. give an example what content is duplicated. You save a dialog with richtext and the properties are duplicated ? what CQ version.

Comment: Sorry for the improper description, the version is 5.6.0. You got it right,i save a dialog with richtext and the properties are duplicated.

Comment: how are they named. you need to give some more hint. e.g. paste a screenshot of how it looks in crx/de after saving the dialog.